# how to make this a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How do I write this as a list comprehension?

```
for i in range(len(genes)):
    if compareGenes(genes[i], target) > count:
        best = genes[i]
        count = compareGenes(genes[i], target)
```

Comment: [Read up](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html); it's more fun that way. :)

Comment: In Python `for` loops over iterators, so looping over indices is a really bad sign - it means you are doing something wrong. ``for gene in genes:`` not ``for i in range(len(genes)):``.

Comment: I like @nneonneo's answer - so much that I gave the same symbol-for-symbol solution. I think he beat me be a few seconds so I withdraw mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`max` with a generator comprehension would be a nice way to go.

```
count, best = max((compareGenes(k, target), k) for k in genes)
```

Alternately, use a `key` argument to `max`:

```
best = max(genes, key=lambda k: compareGenes(k, target))
```